# AngularJS - How to use $routeProvider and custom module in config function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to reuse link. 
How to use $routeProvider and custom module in config function?

```
angular.module('urls', []).
factory('$urls', function (
    $location
    ) {
    var $urls = {};
    $urls.login = function () {
        var url = '/login';
        return url;
    }       
    return $urls;
});   

angular.module('app', ['urls']).
  config(function ($routeProvider, $urls) {
      $routeProvider.
        when($urls.login(), { controller: PageCtrl, templateUrl: 'tem.html' }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: $urls.login() });
});
```

Comment: You can not inject $url in to the config, you can only inject an provider. You might try creating a provider ( instead of a factory ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented you can create a provider instead of a factory and put the URLs in that as the central place:

```
    angular.module('urls', []).
        provider('urls', function (){
            this.$get = function(){    
                 var obj = {}
                 obj.login = function(){ return '/login';}
                 //more urls here, you don't really need function though

                 return obj;
            }
        });

    angular.module('app', ['urls']).
        config(function ($routeProvider, urlsProvider) {
                $routeProvider.
                when(urlsProvider.login(), { controller: PageCtrl, templateUrl: 'tem.html' }).
                otherwise({ redirectTo: urlsProvider.login() });
        });
```

However, you can not inject the $location service to the urls provider. But if you really want to use $location, you can create another service that uses both the urls service and $location service to achieve the same effect like this:

```
    angular.module('urls', []).
        service('myUrlService', function (urls, $location){
                 this.goToLogin = function(){$location.path(urls.login());}//just an example
        });
```

Then you can inject myUrlService to your controllers and do things like this:

```
myUrlService.goToLogin();
```

Comment: Thanks! Could you say, how can I use both - urls and $location services? I try: `angular.module('urls', []).
        provider('urls', function ($location) {
            this.$get = function(){    
                 var obj = {}
                 obj.login = function(redirect){ 
     if (redirect === true)
      $location.url('/login');
     
     return '/login';}
                 //more urls here, you don't really need function though

                 return obj;
            }
        });
 `

Comment: No, you can not inject $location to a provider. you can create a service using either 'service' or 'factory' method. I will update the answer for this